# I converted some downloaded 360° EAC youtube videos but the FOVs always little bit off

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried 2 solutions to watch downloaded 360° EAC videos:

1. Converting EAC videos to traditional equirectangular projection using ffmpeg's V360 filter.

   ```
   ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -vf "v360=c3x2:e:cubic:in_forder='lfrdbu':in_frot='000313',scale=7680:3840,setsar=1:1" -c:v libx264 -preset faster -crf 17 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart OUTPUT.mp4
   ```
2. Using Potplayer's 360 video option and watch: "Equiangular cubemap 3x2(mono 2D)"
   format. it can instantly show EAC 360 videos.
   [Potplayer's 360 video options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3Esq.png)

Both method worked well but converted/played video's FOVs are always went little bit distorted and never look like original EAC youtube videos.

What options should I add when converting the videos with ffmpeg, or is this just how it is without native EAC supported app?

Answer (score 0):

It was input width/height scale. I didn't need to convert EAC to 3:2 cubemap at all but need to convert EAC to equirectangular directly with the video's
original aspect ratio preserved.

So concise code would be like this:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -vf "v360=eac:e,scale=iw:-2" -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -c:a copy OUTPUT.mp4
```

scale=iw: value could be -1 but "height not divisible by 2" error popped up, so value of -2 could fix the error and keep the original aspect ratio.